# Передача данных из php в javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Есть файл php с кодом:

```
<?
$Name = $line['Name'];
$Adres = $line['Adres'];
$Lat = $line['Lat'];
$Lng = $line['Lng'];
?>

<html>  
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/load_map_step.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Т.е. в php я присвоил значения переменным, а теперь хочу к ним обратиться из файла load_map_step.js. Пытаюсь так но ничего не получается, данные пустые...

```
var mylat = $(Lat).val();
var mylong = $(Lng).val();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Их можно передать в JS одним из способов:

- через GET-параметры, если на документ ссылаетесь откуда-то
- встроив значение переменных в DOM-документа
- подгрузив через AJAX с сервера, например, сформировав JSON-ответ
- через cookie
- сформировав JS-код средствами PHP

Самый простой случай - это передача переменных через DOM, можно положить их например в data-атрибут, какого-то скрытого div-документа

```
<?php
$Name = $line['Name'];
$Adres = $line['Adres'];
$Lat = $line['Lat'];
$Lng = $line['Lng'];
?>

<html>  
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/load_map_step.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div
  class='hidden'
  data-name='<?= $Name ?>'
  data-address='<?= $Adres ?>'
  data-lat='<?= $Lat ?>'
  data-lng='<?= $Lng ?>'
></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Тогда если вы пользуетесь jQuery, вы сможете обратится к этим атрибутам через метод data()

```
var mylat = $('div.hidden').data('lat');
var mylong = $('div.hidden').data('lng');
```

Comment: ИМХО, почти идеальный ответ. Осталось лишь добавить json_encode.

Answer (score 4):

У вас не получается потому что к моменту, когда вы пытаетесь обратиться из **js** файла на **машине пользователя** к перемнным, находящимся на **сервере**, то эти переменные уже *"мертвы"*. PHP отработал, отдал данные пользователю, и уже знать не знает что происходит со страницей в браузере у пользователя.
Я бы завел бы файл, например `vars.php`:

```
<? Header("Content-type: application/javascript"); ?>
var Name = <?= $line['Name'];?>
var Adres = <?= $line['Adres'];?>
var Lat = <?= $line['Lat'];?>
var Lng = <?= $line['Lng'];?>
```

В разметке:

```
<html>  
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/vars.php"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/load_map_step.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: завели `vars.php`, а добавляете `src="scripts/vars.js"`

Comment: @Grundy: Поправил.

Comment: Интересно... Реально!

Comment: Так какой в итоге файл нужно создать vars.php или vars.js???

Comment: Заводить надо `php` и с его помощью генерировать js код, примерно как герерируете html код

Answer (score 3):

Так как php исполняется на сервере, а js - на клиенте, один из способов получить значение переменных - просто вывести их в блоке скрипт, например так

```
<?
    $Name = $line['Name'];
    $Adres = $line['Adres'];
    $Lat = $line['Lat'];
    $Lng = $line['Lng'];
?>

<html>  
    <head> 
        <script>
            var Lat='<?= $Lat ?>';
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/load_map_step.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Теперь в момент выполнения скрипта, будет объявлена глобальная переменная, которая будет доступна и внутри подгружаемого скрипта.

Дополнительный вариант: добавить настройки сервера, чтобы js файлы также обрабатывались как php.