# Переменная из php в js

Tags: laravel

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

У меня есть js файл в котором прописано следующее:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let settings = {
        rows: '{{ $rows }}',
        cols: '{{ $cols }}',
        height: '{{ $height }}',
        placesBooking: JSON.parse('{{ $places }}')
    };
```

Переменные приходят с сервера:

```
return view('booking/carriage', [
                        'rows' => 3,
                        'cols' => 18,
                        'height' => 40,
                        'places' => $places
                    ]);
```

Ругается на строку JSON.parse(' {{ $places }} ')

Ошибка: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { in JSON at position

Если код js прописать во вьюшке, тогда всё работает, но если выношу js в отдельный файл и подключаю его, тогда выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача данных из php в javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508826/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-php-%d0%b2-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

PHP код выполняется в файлах с расширением .php

В отдельном js файле он работать не будет, это очевидно же.

Comment: Какое есть альтернативное решение передачи переменной из сервера js файлу?

Comment: @Сергей оставить ваш скрипт во вьюшке

Comment: А чтобы не вставлять скрипт во вьюшке, а вынести в другой файл, нельзя никак?

Comment: @Сергей https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508826/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-php-%D0%B2-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Сделать вьюкомпозер и пусть эти переменные во всех вьюшках будут (т.е. вьюшка *). Но это огромный костыль