# Выбор элемента массива после нажатия php + jquery

Tags: php, html, jquery

В PHP создаётся массив $result5, в который записываются поля из базы данных. Имеются две кнопки, при нажатии на кнопку "Уже знаю" в jquery нужно выбрать следующий элемент массива из PHP. Почему-то событие в jquery срабатывает только один раз, после перезагрузки и нажатия, после второго нажатия следующий элемент массива не выбирается

PHP
`$m=0;
      $result5=array();
      array_push($result5,$result4_1['word']);`

HTML
`<span id="addword"><?php print_r($result5[0]);?></span><br>
        <button onclick = "return false" class="button" id="Yes">Уже знаю</button>
        <button onclick = "return false" class="button" id="No">Учить</button>`

Jquery

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $(document).on("click",".button", function(){
            <?php $m++; ?>
          if (($(this).attr('id'))=="Yes"){
                $('#addword').html("<?php print_r($result5[$m]); ?>");
            }

         });
});
</script>
```

Comment: PHP - скрипты сервера, JS - скрипты в браузере. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/508826/256824

Answer (score 0):

У тебя это не сработает.
PHP скрипт срабатывает только один раз, при загрузке страницы. Либо если направить на него post/get-запрос, но это совсем другая история.
Ты не можешь перемешать PHP и JS таким образом.

Тебе нужно написать отдельным PHP-скриптом все манипуляции с базой данных, а из JS отправлять запросы на этот скрипт, чтобы что-то сделать. Например, с помощью jquery ajax.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Можно ли с тобой как-то связаться по поводу этого вопроса?