# Как передать данные из view laravel в ajax запрос используя jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

Начал разбираться с Laravel и столкнулся с проблемой передачи данных из view в AJAX запрос.

В представлении (view) есть значения, которые мне нужно отправить в скрипт: `{{ $post->message }}` и `{{ $post->created_at }}`. При попытке передать `$post->message` в JavaScript получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $post is not defined

Код скрипта:

```
$('.like').on('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'like',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
    data:  { 
      message: $post->message
    },
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data)
    }
  })
});
```

Как правильно передать данные?

Подозреваю, что нужно "преобразовать" из PHP в формат JS.

Comment: @РустамГимранов если  data:  { 
                {{ $post->message }} 
}, то в консоли Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Передача данных из php в javascript](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508826/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-php-%d0%b2-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще:

```
<?
echo 'var message =" '.$post->message.'"';
?>
```

По идее:

```
var message =  {{ $post->message }} ;
```

Но, я что-то не понимаю как в Laravel кавычки сюда поставить.

Затем:

```
   data:  { 
        message: message },
```

Comment: Если там строка, то `'{{ $post->message }}'`, если число, то не надо кавычек, если объект (массив): `@json($post->message)`. А то и вовсе `{{ $post->message->id }}`. И вы бы уточнили у автора: не  в отдельном ли JS файле он пытается инициализировать PHP переменные.

Comment: Сколько информации, столько и ответа =)

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось проще,я пытался отправить данные из view в public /js/myscript.js
Как только я перенес скрипт в view все отработало