# как получить по запросу только название города и погоду на два дня?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть сайт с погодными данными https://www.weatherapi.com ,нам нужно получить только название города и погоду на 2 дня в этом городе.

Есть запрос :

```
$city = 'London';
$url = file_get_contents('http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=707dee63a73b4df5af152654210704&q=['.$city.
  '],[long]&days=2');
```

Но он возвращает кучу не ненужной информации или как-то можно из этой кипы вытянуть название города и погоду ?

Пример ответа:

```json
{
  "location": {
    "name": "London",
    "region": "City of London, Greater London",
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    "lat": 51.52,
    "lon": -0.11,
    "tz_id": "Europe/London",
    "localtime_epoch": 1618209535,
    "localtime": "2021-04-12 7:38"
  },
  "current": {
    "condition": {},
    "uv": 1.0
  },
  "forecast": {
    "forecastday": [{
      "date": "2021-04-12",
      "date_epoch": 1618185600,
      "day": {
        "condition": {
          "text": "Patchy rain possible",
          "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/176.png",
          "code": 1063
        }
      },
      "astro": {},
      "hour": [{
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }]
    }, {
      "date": "2021-04-13",
      "date_epoch": 1618272000,
      "day": {
        "condition": {
          "text": "Partly cloudy",
          "icon": "//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/day/116.png",
          "code": 1003
        }
      },
      "astro": {},
      "hour": [{
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }, {
        "condition": {}
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Название города можно вытянуть так

```
const city = obj.location.name
```

В каком виде вы хотите погоду? Можно пройтись редьюсом например так

```
const dayArr = obj.forecast.forecastday
const result = dayArr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const date = item.date
  const text = item.day.condition.text
  return {...acc, [date]:text}
}, {})
```

Результатом будет объект, ключ которого - дата, значение - текстовое описание погоды

```
{"2021-04-12":"Patchy rain possible","2021-04-13":"Partly cloudy"}
```

Comment: А не могли бы вы поподробнее рассказать? у меня почему-то  пишет ошибку на obj ?

Comment: За obj я принял тот объект, который вы получаете т.е. const obj = ваш объект

Comment: Видимо,я не так выразился,извините,я имел ввиду ,как передать возвращение запроса ,то есть переменную $url сделать обьектом в JS ?

Comment: Так стоп. В js переменная - это фактически ссылка на объект в памяти. Т.е. ваша переменная url после запроса file_get_contents должна ссылаться на ваш объект. Т.е. const url = file_get_contents('http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=707dee63a73b4df5af152654210704&q=['.$city.'],[long]&days=2'); - это на чистом JavaScript. Или вам принципиально использовать JQuery и $url?

Comment: Подождите,а разве есть такой прямой file_get_contents у JS , он же встроен ,по-моему,в php ,но никак не в JS ?

Comment: Так, теперь я вас понял. Я мало знаком с php и думал что file_get_contents это какая то ваша функция, запрашивабщая данные из вашего api. У вас бэк на php?

Comment: да ,поэтому и загвоздка такая)

Comment: Тогда обработку вам лучше делать на php и не тянуть на фронт кучу ненужных данных. Как передать данные во фронт зависит от вашей реализации, но лучше это делать через внутренне api, а вообще вот почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/508826/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-php-%D0%B2-javascript

Comment: всё-таки получилось сделать объект js,но почему-то Ваш return {...acc, [date]:text} возвращает undefined,хотя obj.location.name работает ,как надо и возвращает название города ,что может быть не так ?

Comment: Это return внутри функции reduce, он отвечает за обновление промежуточного результата и работает корректно только внутри функции reduce. Вы точно запускаете все правильно?

Comment: Извините за беспокойство ,надо было ответить сразу , уже всё сделал - всё работает)

Answer (score 0):

В php есть функция [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php), которая принимает в себя json.

Десериализируем JSON:

```
$obj = json_decode("json");
```

Теперь у вас есть объект **obj**, из которого вы можете вытягивать нужные вам значения по их ключам, достанем например название города:

```
$city = obj->location->name;
```

С другими ключами работаете идентично